# CSS: Circle with four colors and only one div

Tags: css

Is it possible to create a circle with four different colors (one for each quarter) using pure CSS?
I want something like one of these four circles:

[Unfortunately the image I linked to does not exist anymore. Please see the answers to understand the what effect I was after]

I can imagine using a solution with four divs and border-radius, but is this possible using only one div and some fancy css3?

Comment: Can I write rich web applications on assembler? Sure, but why?

Comment: Why I want this in CSS? Zoomability. Why I want only one element? Avoid clutter.
Or what did you mean?

Comment: I don't see any problem with "4 divs inside one div" layout.

Comment: What is wrong with just having that image as a div background???

Comment: I can't see how. Here it is with 4 div's and a container - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4B4P8/)

Comment: you probably can with css gradients. start color, stop start again etc for each circle. still each circle needs to be its own div

Comment: @mishik: Let's say it this way: If there is no way, I will use 4 divs. However, if there is, I prefer the cleaner approach of having just one div.
user2568107: Can't zoom.

Comment: Well, even if there is such way and you get cleaner HTML. Imaging the level of complexity added to CSS.

Comment: I do not know a possible CSS implementation, so I cannot judge its complexity. I just thought there is an easy way, but obviously, there is not.

Comment: @knub, I see what you mean. I was under impression that you want to get four four-colored circles with one div.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since you listed CSS3, you could do this with just borders and a rotation transformation to "fix" the alignment:

```
div {
    border-radius: 50px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 50px;
    border-bottom-color: red;
    border-left-color: green;
    border-right-color: blue;
    border-top-color: yellow;
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;

    /* To ratate */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k8Jj9/

Answer (score 13):

The CSS would be:

```
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, blue, blue 100%), linear-gradient(135deg, green, green), linear-gradient(225deg, yellow, yellow) , linear-gradient(225deg, red, red);
    background-size: 50% 50%;
    background-position: 0% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/R4LJf/)

And with the border radius:

[demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/R4LJf/1/)

**Alternate method**

```
.quarters {
    width: 101px;
    height: 101px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
}

.quarters:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)),                   
                linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6));
    background-size: 50% 100%, 100% 50%;
    background-position: 100% 0%, 0% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  
}

#red {
    background-color: red;
}
#blue {
    background-color: blue;
}
#green {
    background-color: green;
}
#yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

In the line of the OP images, where the circles have different shades of the same color, there is the posibility to define a class that sets to overlays over the base div, both of them semitransparents.
Once defined that class, you can easily apply it to different color elements, getting the same effect without effort

### [Demo 3](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/K9Agf/)

Comment: Note: Always use an even width/height for this solution: otherwise you get white lines.

Comment: Thank you, Could you provide me with a reference to understand the first part of the solution more, please?

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

http://jsbin.com/uletik/1/edit

Just one div.

```
div {
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  border-radius:100px;
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, grey, grey 50%, blue 50%, blue);
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
}
div:after {
  content:"";
  height:50px;
  background-color:red;
  width:50px;
  display:block;
}
div:before {
  content:"";
  background-color:green;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  display:block;
  right:0;
  position:absolute;
}
```